# Filtering out warnings from Box SDK (Python)

Tags: python, box-api

The Box API is noisy ... very helpful for diagnosing, and yet for
production code I'd like less noise.

I tried this:

```
warnings.filterwarnings(
    action='ignore',
    # category=Warning,
    # module=r'boxsdk.*'
)
```

but I still see this:

```
WARNING:boxsdk.network.default_network:"POST
https://api.box.com/oauth2/token" 400 83
{'Date': 'Sat, 28 Nov 2020 04:30:03 GMT', 'Content-Type':
'application/json', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Connection':
'keep-alive', 'Str....
```

My code as written I think should filter ALL warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set logging level of boxsdk module to ERROR or CRITICAL. It will allow you to disable logging of warning messages generated by boxsdk:

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('boxsdk').setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```